# Jenkins: ImportError: No module named requests

Tags: python, jenkins, python-requests

Was trying to execute python script in jenkins, that make HTTP request with help of 'requests' module, but got stuck with following error:

ImportError: No module named requests
Build step 'Custom Python Builder' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: How did you install Python so that Jenkins can use it? Is the requests module installed in this Python installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the dependencies of the script, normally in `setup.py` or `requirements.txt`.

In the case of `requirements.txt` run: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

In the case of `setup.py` run: `pip install .`

You should do this in the job that is running the script.

If neither of these files exist `pip install requests` will include the particular dependency you are missing in your question.